Are there maps not homotopic in dgas? I need and example because I think it isn´t exist.
We say $\varphi_0,\varphi_1:(\bigwedge V,d)\rightarrow (A,d')$ are homotopic if exist a map $H:( \bigwedge V,d)\rightarrow (A,d')\otimes \bigwedge(t,dt)$ such that $(id· \epsilon_0)\circ H=\varphi_0$ and $(id· \epsilon_1)\circ H=\varphi_1$, where $(A,d')$ and $(\bigwedge V,d)$ are a diferential graded-conmutative algebra (dga), i.e, $V=\oplus V^n$ is a graded vectorial space where $V^n$ is a vectorial subspace of V with elements of $n$ degree ($A=\oplus A^n$ is a graded algebra where $A^n$ are vectorial spaces of $n$ degree) and $\epsilon_i:\bigwedge(t,dt)\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ are augmentations maps such that $\epsilon_i(t)=i$. So, a map $f:B\rightarrow A$ between two dgas is a collection of maps $f_n:B^n \rightarrow A^n$.
So, I think if we consider $H(x)=\varphi_1(x) t + \varphi_0 (x)(1-t)=\varphi_1(x) \otimes t + \varphi_0 (x)\otimes(1-t)$ we will get a homotopy between $\varphi_0,\varphi_1$ but I know it's imposible (It's usually denote $a\otimes b=ab$). Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Did you mean to write $H(x,t)$ instead of $H(x)$?

You haven't told us anything about what $V$ is or what $A$ is, or anything. I've read Quillen's original thesis on rationa homotopy, but I can't see any way to understand this question with the tag "rational-homotopy-theory."

The initial space is the same, so we can't write $H(x,t)$ Snared.

I edited the question and I writed more details Thomas Andrews. I apologize.

The mistake is to assume that your formula is multiplicative. Let's take the simplest possible non-trivial example and see that so defined, $H$ is not an algebra map.
Let $A=(\Lambda x,0)$ be the free commutative algebra on a single degree 2 generator, necessarily with trivial differential. Let $\varphi_1$ be the identity of this algebra to itself, and $\varphi_0$ be the constant map equal to zero. Both of these maps are algebra maps. In this particular case, your formula for $H$ returns
$$H(x) = \varphi_1(x)\otimes t + \varphi_0(x)\otimes (1-t) = x\otimes t.$$
Substituting above for $x^2$, we get:
$$H(x^2) = x^2\otimes t.$$
But if we multiply,
$$H(x)\cdot H(x) = (x\otimes t)\cdot (x\otimes t) = x^2\otimes t^2.$$
But $t\neq t^2$, so these two things are not equal.
The connection to rational homotopy theory is that $H$ is a right homotopy in the model category structure on a convenient category of commutative dga's.
